# Jquery add a class to all the parents in the hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent/child hierarchy with child have dynamic length. Which means a child node can be parent of another node etc.

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="tree">
<li id="8587509197182534205xy9w" class="has-children showChildren">
    <i class="fi-minus"></i>

    <div class="checkboxFive">
        <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_8587509197182534205xy9w" value="8587509197182534205xy9w">
        <label for="t_8587509197182534205xy9w"></label>
    </div>

    <span class="text">Sand</span>

    <ul class="child">
        <li id="8587509198220874655a1s8" class="has-children showChildren">
            <i class="fi-minus"></i>


            <div class="checkboxFive">
                <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_8587509198220874655a1s8" value="8587509198220874655a1s8">
                <label for="t_8587509198220874655a1s8"></label>
            </div>

            <span class="text">Fyllgrus</span>
            <ul class="child">
                <li id="8587496924061602638qkdo">
                    <div class="checkboxFive">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_8587496924061602638qkdo" value="8587496924061602638qkdo">
                        <label for="t_8587496924061602638qkdo"></label>
                    </div>

                    <span class="text">sub sub</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li id="8587509198127281697em9f">
            <div class="checkboxFive">
                <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_8587509198127281697em9f" value="8587509198127281697em9f">
                <label for="t_8587509198127281697em9f"></label>
            </div>

            <span class="text">Siltholdig</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li id="8587509197183114344b5l4" class="has-children">
    <i class="fi-plus"></i>
    <div class="checkboxFive">
        <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_8587509197183114344b5l4" value="8587509197183114344b5l4">
        <label for="t_8587509197183114344b5l4"></label>
    </div>

    <span class="text">Leire</span>
    <ul class="child">
        <li id="85875091985832885997g4j">
            <div class="checkboxFive">
                <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_85875091985832885997g4j" value="85875091985832885997g4j">
                <label for="t_85875091985832885997g4j"></label>
            </div>

            <span class="text">Bløt</span>
        </li>
        <li id="858750919842507621898j6">
            <div class="checkboxFive">
                <input type="checkbox" name="massTypeId" class="massTypeTreeId" id="t_858750919842507621898j6" value="858750919842507621898j6">
                <label for="t_858750919842507621898j6"></label>
            </div>

            <span class="text">Tørr</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I am trying to achieve is whenever a child node is selected, it goes up until the root and select all the parents in the hierarchy. Something like this:

[image]

So when I select sub sub in the image the parents are selected as well. I have a class which designs the parent checked checkboxes. I want to add that class to all the parent div with class 'checkboxFive'. Is there an easy way in jquery to do that or I would have to add it using recursion?

Comment: maybe you should use the ´parents()´ function with a selector, see https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While everyone else has mentioned `JQuery.parents()` already, it may be worth noting that `parents()` can take a selector as an argument. As far as I understand your answer, you want to apply some special class (which I will refer to as `parentCheckbox` in this answer) to any parent checkbox with the `checkboxFive` class. You can do this by doing:

```
$(<JQuery selector for whatever you want to set this for>).change(function() {
  $(this).parents(".checkboxFive").addClass("parentCheckbox");
});
```

All you need to do then is figure out a) what you want to apply the onchange function to:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]")
```

or

```
$(".tree input[type=checkbox"]")
```

if you want to ensure that it is only applied to checkboxes within a `ul` of class `tree`.

You could also be more specific about your the `parents()` selector and do something like `parents(".tree .checkboxFive").addClass...` to ensure that nothing outside the tree gets checked.

Answer (score 1):

Created an Example for you. You can easily understand this and implement the same to your situation. This will make the color of all the text inside each `<div>` as red.

```
<div>
    GrandParent
    <div>
       Parent
       <div id="test">
           Child
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery("#test").parents("div").css("color" , "red");
</script>
```